# Galvanic cell - when do we get electric potential?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, voltage, electrochemistry

In the galvanic cell in this image (2nd one with salt bridge): [Link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28567/133692)

Before putting the copper wire into the solution, do the Zn metal electrons have potential energy with respect to Cu2+'s electric field? The reason I'm asking is that there must be an electric potential difference between the anode and the cathode, hence the electrons moving from the anode to the cathode must have decreasing potential energy, which means they had to have potential energy to begin with. But then, when and where did the Zn valence electrons get this potential energy from?

Comment: In the electrolyte and in the metal, the current flows from the higher potential to the lower potential. On the other hand, at the boundary between the anode electrode and the electrolyte and between the cathode electrode and the electrolyte, the current flows in the opposite direction of the potential gradient. This is probably due to the EMFs in the opposite direction. Since electric potential is a single valued function, electric potential alone cannot explain the direction of current. I believe the origin of EMFs in batteries is unknown.

Comment: When do Zn metal valence electrons get this potential energy - before or after connecting the wire ?

Comment: Comparing the case of a bean bulb in a battery with the circuit closed and switched on with the circuit open and switched off, we estimate that the EMF values are almost the same in both cases, but the potential distribution is immediately different and the total electric field is zero, although the EMF is non-zero even in the open circuit.

Comment: Electrons don't move in a galvanic cell. The current is carried by ions.

Comment: The thing that you are asking for is actually quite complicated. There is simply a difference in the amount of energy needed to pull two electrons off a Zn atom v.s. a Cu atom. The galvanic cell battery exploits this energy difference in such a way that it sets up the potential energy difference, and thus the potential difference. The potential is not originally there before the setup is working. The dipping into the same electrolytic solution is needed to set up the potential.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent forget about battery.  just the 2nd image from my link only. In there,  since waters/solutions are in different containers, without putting wire into them, do we have potential energy or not ? if not, does putting the wire cause it to gain potential energy and how ?

Comment: The galvanic cell IS the battery. Potential energy is there even before the potential difference is created. If you have the wire but no solution, then there is no potential difference, even though there is potential energy. If you have the solution but no wire, then there is potential energy and potential difference. If you have both solution and wire, then electrons flow, using the potential energy and potential difference to do something.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent So since the solution gets us Cu2++, its electric field exists and Zn's electrons feel this field hence why you're saying that if solution exists, thats why we got potential difference as well ? but since the solutions are in different containers of water and they are quite not close, how do we get this potential difference ? at the cathode, Cu2++ start to still attracting them even without wire ? is this not negligible ?

Comment: Getting closer. Each of the two solutions are trying to get into thermal equilibrium with $\text{Cu}\Leftrightarrow\text{Cu}^{2+}+2e^-$ and $\text{Zn}\Leftrightarrow\text{Zn}^{2+}+2e^-$. The potential difference for each of these two chemical equations are different, and that is the true source of the potential difference in the wire later on. Yes, the potential difference and electric field can actually affect that far away (mostly because of the wire), but that part is not the important concept. The chemical balance is the important concept.

Comment: What confuses me is that first, potential energy has to exist in order to get potential difference.  If we have the wire, but no solution, how do we have potential energy ? are you referring the potential energy of Zn's valence electrons(still bound to Zn) in respect to Cu's metal on the other side of the wire ? or in respect to what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145951/discussion-between-omar-shekriladze-and-naturallyinconsistent).

Answer (score 1):

The potential comes from the chemical energy of the reaction. In fact if the Gibbs free energy for the reaction is $\Delta G$ then the EMF is simply:

$$ ΔG = -zFE \tag{1} $$

where $z$ is the number of electrons involved in the reaction ($z = 2$ in this case) and $F$ is the charge of a mole of electrons. This is the [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation).

Suppose we move a charge $q$ through a potential $E$ then work needed to do this is simply:

$$ W = qE $$

For the reaction:

$$ \mathrm{Zn} + \mathrm{Cu}^{2+} \to \mathrm{Zn}^{2+} + \mathrm{Cu} $$

we are moving two moles of electrons, i.e. a charge $2F$, for every mole of zinc that reacts so if the cell EMF is $E$ the work done per mole of zinc reacting is $2FE$. The energy required for this work comes from the energy of the reaction and hence we get equation (1).

Comment: I think the Gibbs free energy argument is probably correct, but it is thermodynamics, so it is a law for many-particle systems. For minority particle systems, I would like to know what happens to the electric field applied to individual charged particles.